# How to use a specific column on the X-axis of a DataFrame plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I want my plot to use State names on the x-axis, not the index values.
This code produces the graph:

```
print(df.info())
print(df)
df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.xlabel('State')
plt.ylabel('Total Sales')
plt.title('Total Sales by State')
plt.show()
```

This is the output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 11 entries, 0 to 10
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------           --------------  -----  
 0   State            11 non-null     object 
 1   SumOfTotalPrice  11 non-null     float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 304.0+ bytes
None
   State  SumOfTotalPrice
0     AK     1.063432e+07
1     CA     4.172891e+07
2     IL     2.103149e+07
3     IN     2.270681e+08
4     KY     4.144238e+07
5     ME     2.057557e+07
6     MI     4.216375e+07
7     OH     7.970354e+08
8     PA     2.158148e+07
9     SD     1.025623e+07
10    TX     2.061534e+07
```

The plot doesn't have the state names on the X-axis:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried ax.set_xticks()

Comment: All you need is `ax = df.plot(kind='bar', x='State', figsize=(10, 8))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the index values are used as labels.

You can set column `State` as index of your dataframe before plotting:

```
df = df.set_index("State")
```

Then the plot will have column `State` values as label for the x-axis:
[image]